# Easier way to extract only prefixed elements from mixed xml/html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my working nightmare: we have a bunch of files that are html pages but which contain additional xml elements (all prefixed with our company name 'TLA') to provide data and structure for an older program which I am now rewriting.

Example Form:

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>Highly Simplified Example Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <TLA:document>
        <TLA:contexts>
            <TLA:context id="id_1" value=""></TLA:context>
        </TLA:contexts>
        <TLA:page>
            <TLA:question id="q_id_1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="input_id_1" type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </TLA:question>
        </TLA:page>
        <!-- Repeat many times -->
    </TLA:document>
</body>
</html>
```

My task is to write a pre-processor that will split a document like this into two documents: an xml file containing only the 'TLA' elements and an html file containing only the html elements.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TLA:document>
    <TLA:contexts>
      <TLA:context id="id_1" value=""></TLA:context>
    </TLA:contexts>
    <TLA:page>
      <TLA:question  id="q_id_1">
      </TLA:question>
    </TLA:page>
    <!-- Repeat many times -->
</TLA:document>
```

Example HTML:

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>Highly Simplified Example Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="input_id_1" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Repeat many times -->
</body>
</html>
```

Now I can do this by processing each element one at a time and copying them to new documents but I'm thinking that there might be an easier way to do this by using a one or two pass transform or some clever serialization but I have no idea which avenues to explore.

So does anyone have a suggestion as to how to process this? Ideally VB.net but C# or something else is also acceptable.

Update:

It seems that xslt is the way to do this but I know so little about it that I still need some help. It seems that  //namespace::TLA may be the right xpath to extract the data elements but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Should be very easy in XSLT, especially in XSLT 2.0. But I would need to have a better understanding of your desired output: can you show the two documents you want from this source? (Especially when TLA:page is repeated)

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the suggestion, I've added example outputs too. XSLT is a new area for me so I'm not at all sure of what it can do.

Comment: I agree that XSLT would be the best option, but only IF the complete input file is well-formed XML.  Sometimes HTML is well formed-XML, but it doesn't have to be, so often it isn't.  If it isn't, you may have to manually parse the file to look for a specific start and end tag, or if that is a variable thing, you may want to look into something like the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: HTML Agility Pack FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT was the best choice for solving this problem.

- To extract the HTML see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827349/copy-only-html-from-mixed-xml-and-html).
- To extract the namespace see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813724/copy-all-elements-of-a-namespace-and-nothing-else).