# Closing tags when extracting HTML from XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, visual-studio-2012

I am transforming a mixed html and xml document using an xslt stylesheet and extracting only the html elements.

Source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html >
  <head>
    <title>Simplified Example Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <TLA:document xmlns:TLA="http://www.TLA.com">
      <TLA:contexts>
        <TLA:context id="id_1" value=""></TLA:context>
      </TLA:contexts>
      <table id="table_logo" style="display:inline">
        <tr>
          <td height="20" align="middle">Big Title Goes Here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <img src="logo.jpg" border="0"></img>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <TLA:page>
        <TLA:question id="q_id_1">
          <table id="table_id_1">
            <tr>
              <td>Label text goes here</td>
              <td>
                <input id="input_id_1" type="text"></input>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </TLA:question>
      </TLA:page>
      <!-- Repeat many times -->
    </TLA:document>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:TLA="http://www.TLA.com" exclude-result-prefixes="TLA">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.0" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This element-only identity template prevents the 
       TLA namespace declaration from being copied to the output -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Pass processing on to child elements of TLA elements -->
  <xsl:template match="TLA:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Simplified Example Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table_logo" style="display:inline">
      <tr>
        <td height="20" align="middle">Big Title Goes Here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="logo.jpg" border="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table_id_1">
      <tr>
        <td>Label text goes here</td>
        <td><input id="input_id_1" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

However there's a problem in that the meta, img, and input elements are not being closed correctly. I've set the xsl:output to html and the version to 4.0 so as far as I know they *should* output correct html.

I'm guessing that there needs to be a subtle change in the first xsl:template/xsl:copy instruction but my xslt skills are highly limited.

What change needs to be made to get the tags to close correctly?

P.S. I'm not sure if there's a difference between different tools/parsers but I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to debug the stylesheet so that I can see the immediate effect of any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<meta>`, `<img>` and `<input>` elements don't need to be closed — it's still valid HTML.

If you want to have them closed, you could use `xml` (with XSLT2.0 you could use `xhtml`, too, as far as I know) as the output method and add the `<meta>` tag yourself if you need it. For example:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:TLA="http://www.TLA.com" exclude-result-prefixes="TLA">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head">
    <xsl:copy>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This element-only identity template prevents the 
       TLA namespace declaration from being copied to the output -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Pass processing on to child elements of TLA elements -->
  <xsl:template match="TLA:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Simplified Example Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table_logo" style="display:inline">
      <tr>
        <td height="20" align="middle">Big Title Goes Here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <img src="logo.jpg" border="0"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table_id_1">
      <tr>
        <td>Label text goes here</td>
        <td>
          <input id="input_id_1" type="text"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you don't understand the syntax rules for SGML based HTML which HTML 4 or 4.01 is: the correct markup for an empty element is `<input>`, it is not `<input></input>` nor `<input/>` nor `<input />`.

So with your request of the HTML output method and version you get the correct HTML syntax when the result tree of your XSLT transformation is serialized.

Check for instance http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.arcor.de%2Fmartin.honnen%2Fxslt%2Ftest2013040901Result.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0, there are no errors or warnings on elements not being closed properly in there.

However with http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.arcor.de%2Fmartin.honnen%2Fxslt%2Ftest2013040902Result.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 you get warnings that elements are incorrectly closed.

So the `html` output method does the right thing, see also http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method which says:

> The html output method should not output an end-tag for empty
>   elements. For HTML 4.0, the empty elements are area, base, basefont,
>   br, col, frame, hr, img, input, isindex, link, meta and param. For
>   example, an element written as `<br/>` or `<br></br>` in the stylesheet
>   should be output as `<br>`.